# How do i sync the postgres db to AWS EC2 db instance via S3?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to syn Postgres data between my server to AWS EC2 DB instance via S3.

Comment: I don't know why is S3 important in your setup, but the replication can be done using the in-built streaming replication. Or you can even use pgpool to replicate and load balancing between the master and slaves. More details here - https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/02/21/three-approaches-to-postgresql-replication/

Comment: I don't want to open up an inbound port to connect db in EC2 Instance. That's what I'm planning to do via s3.

Comment: Then some process on the your server itself should backup it and upload to s3 and then ec2 instance can restore this backup - this will only achieve backup-restore and not sync. For replication, the 2 servers should be able to see each other.

Comment: Yes, I can do the initial setup using backup and restore. Then how can I do a sync? Full backup and restoration are very expensive.

Comment: Just check out the streaming replication in postgresql - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication  This just needs the primary DB open to the slave, so if your ec2 instance is a slave, you just need to open your local port. And the WALs can be shipped to S3. (check the link to see  what is WAL shipping and why is needed in streaming replication)